# How to get the file path of a dropped folder in delphi firemonkey2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Hi as the title says i want to know what code i should use and how i would go about setting up my program so that when i drag a file over a panel or the main form,
It gives me the file path of that folder.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

- Put a TDropTarget component on the main form.
- Set the Filter property.  Put * instead of *.* if you want it to accept folders as well as files.
- In the OnDropped event, the list of fully qualified file and or folder names is in Data.Files.  You should be able to get everything you need from there.

Is this what you are trying to accomplish, or do you have something else in mind?

**Update:**

By request, added an example that shows the name of the first file that was dropped.

```
procedure TForm1.DropTarget1Dropped(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
begin
  ShowMessage(Data.Files[0]);
end;
```

Comment: Im testing now, and yes this is what i am trying to accomplish. Thanks

Comment: Can you mabye add code that shows how to display the file name in a showmessage?

Comment: I added a simple example.  Note that you can drag several files, but this example just displays the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked, i have another question : How do i filter the droptarget so that it only allows folders

Comment: I don't think you can use the filter alone to do this, but you can check the file(s) being dragged in the OnDragOver event and decide what to accept or not.  If you need more details, you should ask in a separate question.